# How can all the icon images for Corona SDK apps be generated from a single image file?

Tags: image-processing, icons, coronasdk

To properly customize the app icons for various platforms when using the Corona SDK game engine, a fairly large set of image files of specific sizes needs to be included in the project's root directory and specified in the `build.settings` file (detailed requirements are found in the [Building/Distribution Dev Guide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#appicons).

Is there any way to easily generate all the required image files for iOS and Android builds starting with a single, hi-res image file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use generator [Icon Generator for Corona SDK](http://icon.angrymarmot.org) with my previous game.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions using various image processing apps can be found [on the Corona Community Forum](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/67303-icon-generator-script/).  My own solution was to write a Script-Fu script in Scheme for GIMP.

For those who are interested, the script (make-corona-icons.scm) and its README (with bare bones installation instructions) can be found in this [public GitHub repository](https://github.com/TastyGreg/GIMP-Script-Fu-Scripts).  GIMP, the open-source cross-platform "GNU Image Manipulation Program", is free and excellent and can be [downloaded here](https://www.gimp.org/).

Answer (score -1):

I use [makeappicon.com](https://makeappicon.com). It has treated me well for many years.